# IOS Predicate to search in a sentence

Tags: ios, search, nspredicate

I am using the predicate

```
NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Title contains[cd] %@", searchText];
    searchResult = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [InitialArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate]];
```

This returns if the searchtext is a string. But my InitialArray values are sentences and not single words. Ex., "Today is Saturday", and when i type "Today", it picks, but if i continue to type "Today is" it won't come in search results. Please guide!!

Comment: You will have to include actual examples here. If your array contains the sentence "today is blah" then the search text "today" and "today is" and "is b" will all return that sentence. Your example seems like it should work.

Comment: Also, variable names begin with a lowercase letter. Class names begin with an uppercase letter. Your array should not be called `InitialArray` it should be `initialArray`. Same with the property `title`.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, my sentences are large ones like, "rama is going to hospital today!". If my search string is "going to hospital", then only 1st item in the list is displayed and not the current one. If its "going to", it seems to be listed fine!

Comment: You should add an answer so that anyone with the same problem can see what your solution was.